# Adding JSON values into a list

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, list, nested

I'm wanting to iterate through my JSON file, and add two values into a list.

In theory, I'm wanting to have a nested list as: `ips = [["custom3","modemId"],["custom3","modemId"]]` and so on. My JSON file has 171 of each custom3 and modemId values. So in theory my nested list will contain 171 lists.

I'm having trouble adding the values into a list, in which I would like to append each list together, to create 171 lists.

```
json1 = open('C:\\Users\\' + comp_name + '\\Documents\\Programming Projects\\Python\\Python Firmware Script\\curl\\src\\out.json')
json1_obj = json.load(json1)

for i in json1_obj['data']:
    ip = [i['custom3']['modemId']]
```

A snippet of my JSON data:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "custom3": "192.168.243.132",
            "modemId": "000408"
        },
        {
            "custom3": "192.168.244.156",
            "modemId": "000310"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have 171 objects as above, but I'm only showing two. From the above, I would like to create two lists and append them each into a nested list.

How do I iterate through each JSON object and create a nested list with my JSON data in Python?

Comment: Array inside an array or an array of dicts?

Comment: After you load the json, it's just normal python lists and dictionaries

Comment: @cricket_007 I don't know how to iterate through my JSON objects and add two values into a list. With the above code, I'm getting the following error `string indices must be integers`

Comment: Yes, `i['custom3']` is a string... And you indexed by not using a integer

Comment: By the way, your json snippet isn't valid.

Comment: If that's the exact layout of the dict you are going to have a problem if the ip's are not strings.

Comment: @rosh My bad, they are strings. cricket_007 Sorry about that, my original JSON is valid, but this was just a quick whip up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, once loaded the json is a python dictionary.
You should now iterate on the value of the 'data' key, extract the information and store them in a list.

Something like this should do the job:

```
json_obj = json.load(json1)

ips = []
for piece in json_obj['data']:
    this_ip = [piece['custom3'], piece['modemId']]
    ips.append(this_ip)
```

One line form:

```
ips = [[piece['custom3'], piece['modemId']] for piece in json_obj['data']]
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much. Very interesting indeed, I was just stuck on adding the two values into a list.

Comment: You could do the same in one line ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want this

```
ips = [["custom3","modemId"],["custom3","modemId"]]
```

Then all you need is a simple list comprehension

```
ips = [d.keys() for d in json1_obj['data']]
```

If you want to actually get the values (in order), not the keys

```
ips = [ [ d['custom3'], d['modemId'] ]  for d in json1_obj['data']]
```

Comment: This is handy indeed, unfortunately, my JSON objects hold a lot more data than what I had specified, sorry about that! Printing my list prints every single value. I only need two values from my JSON objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the values of custom3 and modemIds, you could do,

```
[item.values() for item in json_data['data']]
```